# Better way to return value from a Groovy closure in Gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy

The below code works. It gets a collection of all the different task groups in Gradle and prints them out. I was hoping there was a better way to do this. Part of the problem is the only way I can access all tasks is via the `all()` method which has this signature `void all(Closure var1);` which is very frustrating because of just returning a collection, I get a closure that can iterate over the collection.

```
afterEvaluate { Project project ->
    def blah = []
    project.tasks.all { Object object ->
        blah << object.group
    }
    println blah.unique()
}
```

I was hoping there was a better way to do this than stashing values in a variable defined outside the closure. The primary problem here is that as the closure runs I only have access to one group name at a time, and I want to unique them, and I can't return anything from the all function because the return type is void.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As project.tasks is a collection, have you tried something like

```
afterEvaluate { Project project ->
    println project.tasks.collect { it.group }.unique()
}
```

Comment: It's a collection? I thought it was a https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskContainer.html

Comment: Okayyy after digging through the api documentation for https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/TaskContainer.html it implements https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html?is-external=true which is enhanced by groovy as http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#collect()